# How to wrap a button's text/value in a span?

Tags: jquery

Very simple issue. I need to wrap the button's text (Buy Now) in a span. Can anyone suggest how I might do that using jQuery?

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="22706" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Buy Now</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( '.button' ).wrapInner( "<span class='test'></span>");
```

Comment: This will wrap the entire button if I'm not mistaken, not only the text contents.

Comment: Yes, this wraps the button but I need to wrap the 'text contents'.

Comment: @BrianyHearne sorry, my bad of reading. :) Check updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace any HTML markup by using jQuery's .replaceWith() method.

If you want to keep the existing markup, you could use code like this:

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').replaceWith('<span>' + $('.single_add_to_cart_button').html() +'</span>')
```